# Is there a module that allow to access a page using a specific URL?

Tags: 7, users

I remember seeing this module a while ago, but can't for the life of me finding it. What it did was to only allow a page to be accessible by a specific link you set for it. So, if you just entered the URL into your browser, you would be redirected to, say, your home page.

Does anyone recall this module?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The difference between clicking a link and entering a URL should be none. And if it is, it's security by obscurity at best.

Comment: I believe it used some sort of tokening system on the referring link.  Otherwise, if the url of the page is entered, you would get a 404.

Comment: So you're looking for a "temporary url" creator, and something that blocks access to the target pages unless referred by such a temporary url? Unfortunately I'm not familiar with such a module.

Comment: Yeah, something to that effect.

Comment: Are you sure you are not referring to a couple of modules? I cannot find a single module that redirect from a URL to another that uses tokens, but using two different modules you can get a redirect, and use tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing something similar with the [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) a while ago.

Take a look at the integrations for extended functionality - I think you can use the [Tokens module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) with it.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options:

1. By keeping the url just using an alias: http://www.your-site.tld/admin/config/search/path/add

Existing system path * http://www.your-site.tld/node/NID (also=http://www.your-site.tld/lang/content/long-existing-url-blabla)
Path alias * http://www.your-site.tld/here

2. Using a shortened url with the [shorten module](https://www.drupal.org/project/shorten) to create a url alias like yste.co/loc